# SQL how i can convert from datetime to total hours?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I do this query and the result is a datetime, i try so much variants, but nothing work it... I want the result to be displayed in the number of total hours, like (in this case): 25:01:05 because i have 2 days en this datetime, I have had results like 01:01:05 which is when it only subtracts the hours from the datetime. I would like that as well as add the hours by the number of days, do it with the months if it can be

[image]

Comment: add sql code. ypu should be able to convert date to seconds and get difference then do absolute value and convert to a period

Answer (score 0):

The `time` datatype in SQL Server only holds up to 24 hours.

I would recommend decimal hours instead:

```
select datediff(second, 0, calchstrabajos) / (60.0 * 60)
```

Note:  I switched from millisecond to second because that is usually sufficient.

If you want this in the form of HH:MM:SS, then you would need to convert to a string.  I don't recommend that.